# Is USB2 too slow to stream videos from a wifi network?

Tags: wireless-networking, usb-storage

I plan to get a network USB hub to hook to my router and then I want to stick a portable hard drive in which I plan to have all my videos and music.

Is this a good option? Is USB 2.0 too slow for streaming video? Or do I pretty much need to invest in like a dedicated network hard drive like this one (http://dicksmith.com.au/product/XM1286/seagate-goflex-home-2tb-network-storage-hard-drive). It just seems kind of pricey.

Answer (score 1):

Bluray requires 36MB/s, or 54MB/s for video, thus 54g wireless network is too slow, and USB 2.0 might be a bit too slow for good video.
You will need wireless-N everywhere on your way to be able to stream all hd videos (some may work with 54Mbps wireless ...

Comment: If you are using anything other than straight up blue ray rips with no re-encoding the wifi should work fine. The average bitrate of a re-encoded video is MUCH lower than the source media.

Comment: Is USB faster or wirelessN faster? If wireless N is faster, if I plug my portable hard drive into my laptop and run a video from there, would that be exactly the same performance as having the hard drive remotely?

Comment: I would suggest testing your portable hard drive to see if it has a decent throughput.  I've noticed that many flash drives at least, despite being USB 2.0, have terrible throughput rates. In all cases, USB should be faster, but that depends on the device itself. If the device is slow, then the performance over the wireless won't be good either since it would get limited by the USB connection before even getting to the Wireless N.

Comment: USB 2.0 *480Mbps* 60MB/s
Wireless-N *300Mbps* 38MB/s

Wireless-G *54Mbps* 6.75MB/s (symmetric, so 3MB/s)

Bluray - 432Mbps 54MB/s

HDD - 800Mbps 100MB/s

Thus obviously you cannot stream HD movie over wireless withouttranscoding, though you will not have problem with USB2.0 blu-ray drive yet.

Comment: Blu-ray video's max data transfer rate is 54 megabits per second, not 54 MebiBytes. If you had a 12x BD burner you could burn a disc at 54 MebiBytes/sec, but we shouldn't use that fact to confuse a conversation about video transfer rates. Also, please consider taking the mega->Mebi conversion into account. But I think your point may still stand.

Comment: Somebody wrote wrong capitalisation on the internet .... thus you can NOT see BD titles ofer wireless-g